# What does grep -Po '...\K...' do? How else can that effect be achieved?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this script `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_path=$1
result=$(grep -Po 'value="\K.*?(?=")' $file_path)
echo $result
```

and this file `text.txt`:

```
value="a"
value="b"
value="c"
```

When I run `./script.sh /file/directory/text.txt` command, the output in the terminal is the following:

```
a b c
```

I understand what the script does, but I don't understand HOW it works, so I need a **detailed** explanation of this part of command:

```
-Po 'value="\K.*?(?=")'
```

If I understood correctly, `\K` is a Perl command. Can you give me an alternative in shell (for example with `awk` command)?

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: @jwodder I have edited it.

Comment: Have you *tried* reading `man grep`, and looking for `-P` and `-o`? The description of `-P` is actually likely to make the rest rather obvious.

Comment: BTW, I've edited the question title to make that title specific to the question being asked. Please try to do that yourself in the future.

Comment: As another aside -- failure to quote `$file_path` actually means you've got some bugs -- passing a filename that's in a directory named `My Documents` would go badly. Always quote your expansions: `"$file_path"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `grep -P` enables PCRE syntax. (This is a non-standard extension -- not even all builds of GNU grep support it, as it depends on the optional libpcre library, and whether to link this in is a compile-time option).
- `grep -o` emits only matched text, and not the entire line containing said text, in output. (This too is nonstandard, though more widely available than `-P`).
- `\K` is a PCRE extension to regex syntax discarding content prior to that point from being included in match output.

Since your shell is bash, you have ERE support built in. As an alternative that uses only built-in functionality (no external tools, `grep`, `awk` or otherwise):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
regex='value="([^"]*)"'                    # store regex (w/ match group) in a variable
results=( )                             # define an empty array to store results
while IFS= read -r line; do             # iterate over lines on input
  if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then        # ...and, when one matches the regex...
    results+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )   # ...put the group's contents in the array
  fi
done <"$1"                              # with stdin coming from the file named in $1
printf '%s\n' "${results[*]}"           # combine array results with spaces and print
```

---

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression for a discussion of `=~`, and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#bash_rematch for a discussion of `BASH_REMATCH`. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a discussion of reading files line-by-line with a `while read` loop.

Comment: Wouldn't it rather be `value="([^"]*)"'` to emulate non-greediness?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You have used result variable as an array. Could you please edit your code so the result variable is of same type of this: `result=$(grep -Po 'value="\K.*?(?=")' $file_path)` (a string I guess)? Sorry for my english

Comment: @OrdinaryUser, I used an array very intentionally -- if you're going to use your result like `echo $result`, then you're string-splitting it (into words on whitespace characters) and evaluating each of those words generated by the splitting operation as a glob. That's an innately error-prone operation, and it means you can't tell the difference between having one value of `"hello world"` and two separate values, where the first is `hello` and the second is `world`. With an array, the boundary divisions are known and fixed, and you can always go from that array *to* a string later.

Comment: @OrdinaryUser, ...so, for instance: `if (( ${#results[@]} )); then printf -v result '%s\n' "${results[@]}"; else result=''; fi` will generate a single string named `result` with boundaries separated by newlines. `echo $result` won't show those newlines, but `echo "$result"` will -- that's probably the best parallel for the original code.

Comment: Very, very nice advice for bash only alternate to GNU core tools.

Comment: @Cymatical, this can be needed even on systems that _do_ use GNU tools; the dependency of GNU grep on libpcre (which is used to provide `-P`) is a compile-time option and can be turned off.