# grep with PCRE on macOS

Tags: bash, grep, pcre

I'm using this linux grep command

`grep -Po 'uc-download-link" [^>]* href="\K[^"]*' | sed 's/\&amp;/\&/g'`

that fails on `macOS`.

In this command, `grep -P` enables PCRE syntax, while `grep -o` emits only matched text - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524643/what-does-grep-po-k-do-how-else-can-that-effect-be-achieved).
Does macOs grep support `PCRE`.

Comment: You need `pcregrep`. Possible duplicate of [grep -P no longer works how can I rewrite my searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew changed the title, since it's not a duplicate, it's specific to macOS, while that referred question it is not.

Comment: It is still a duplicate. You still need to install the `grep` version for MacOS that supports PCRE regexps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay, but it does not answer my question. I try to edit it to make more clear.

Comment: macOS built-in `grep` does not. Use **homebrew** to install `GNU grep` like this `brew install grep`.

Comment: If none of the answers in the duplicate work for you, please [edit] your question to explain why you cannot use Perl or `pcregrep` or any of the other solutions there.  You should understand that "duplicate question" on Stack Overflow basically means "the answers to the duplicate question answer this question, too"; so don't get distracted if you are being directed to a duplicate question which is superficially different from yours.

Comment: you were right it's a duplicate. Shall I delete or close?