# Grep for substring from piped output lookbehind assertion

Tags: linux, grep

I am using xinput to get the following data:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My intention is to retrieve the id of AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick **in one line only**. So, I tried the following:

```
xinput | grep -Po "(?<=DualPoint Stick\s.+id=())"
grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PCRE only supports fixed length look behind. No repetition operators like `+`. Not sure why you're using look behind in the first place though.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your required output from that sample input. Good luck.

Comment: And why always make it so hard, `sed '/^.*DualPoint Stick * id=/s///;s/  .*$//'` (or very close anyway). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
xinput | grep -Po 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick *id=\K[0-9]+'
```

Output:

```
11
```

---

See: [What does grep -Po '…\K…' do? How else can that effect be achieved?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44524643/3776858)

Comment: Did not work. I get the result using this instead `xinput | grep -Po 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick\s+id=\K[0-9]+'`

Comment: Okay, output contains multiple spaces and one tab.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity who might be on an HP laptop looking for touchpad help,

```
xinput | grep -Po '.*Touchpad\s+id=\K[0-9]+
```